# Angular - Images won't show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have data coming from my database.  Each record has an image path.  I'm trying to show the image using the path but the images will not show.

Here is my controller:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('ContractorCtrl', function ($scope, $interval, $window) {

    $scope.items = [
   "ContractorWidget/yellow_triangle.png",
   "ContractorWidget/yellow_triangle.png",
   "ContractorWidget/yellow_triangle.png",
   "ContractorWidget/yellow_triangle.png",
   "ContractorWidget/yellow_triangle.png",
   "ContractorWidget/red_cross.png"

    ];

});
```

Here is my HTML:

<

```
div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="ContractorCtrl">
<div class="newWidget">
            <ul class="grid-wrap one-whole">
                <li ng-repeat="item in items" class="grid-col one-quarter">
                    <div>
                        <img ng-src="~/Images/{{item}}" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried using both "src" and "ng-src" but neither works.  Any ideas as to what I am missing here?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe problem with path, check console for 404

Comment: Thanks, but the path is correct.  Images display correctly if I hard code the path in the img tag rather than trying to render from Angular controller.  this "img src="~/Images/ContractorWidget/green_check.png" displays correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Mod Your JSON

```
 $scope.items = [
  {url: "ContractorWidget/yellow_triangle.png"},
  {url: "ContractorWidget/yellow_triangle.png"},
  {url: "ContractorWidget/yellow_triangle.png"},
  {url: "ContractorWidget/yellow_triangle.png"}
];
```

Then in html

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" class="grid-col one-quarter">
      <div>
           <img ng-src="~/Images/{{item.url}}" />
      </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Why? What is the problem with array?

Comment: when using angular real JSON is just the way I do it, everythings easier with JSON. Especially if your going for a full mean stack

Comment: Thanks Joe!  That was all that was needed.  When I actually get the images from the database, the format will be JSON.  The hard coding was just to test my view.  Thanks a million!

Comment: no probs, glad to help :)
best of luck with your web app

Answer (score 1):

Your `ng-repeat` with an array is not working because you have duplicate items.

Use `track by $index` :

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" class="grid-col one-quarter">
    <img ng-src="~/Images/{{item}}" />
</li>
```

Modifying the json is a way to get around the problem, as objects in the array have distinct references, even if the values are the same.